# excel text matching with pdf and copy paste excel text in pdf file

Tags: python, excel, pdf, matching

how to create python code for matching date in column in excel sheet with pdf file the paste data from adjacent data from column in excel sheet in pdf file under name.
i have tried this code;

```
import openpyxl
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
```

## `Read Excel data`

```
excel_file = 'C:/Users/ADMIN/Documents/EXCELTOPDF/list.xlsx'
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
worksheet = workbook.active
```

## `Read PDF data`

```
pdf_file = 'C:/Users/ADMIN/Documents/EXCELTOPDF/labels.pdf'
pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)
```

## `Perform data matching and manipulation`

```
for row_excel in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
  name = row_excel[0]
  sku = row_excel[1]
    
# Find the matching page in the PDF
for page in pdf_reader.pages:
  text = page.extract_text()
  if name in text:
  # Find the blank space under the name and paste the SKU
    updated_text = text.replace(name, f"{name}\n{sku}")
    page.set_text(updated_text)
```

## `Save the updated PDF file`

```
output_file = 'C:/Users/ADMIN/Documents/EXCELTOPDF/labels1.pdf'
pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
for page in pdf_reader.pages:
  pdf_writer.add_page(page)

with open(output_file, 'wb') as f:
  pdf_writer.write(f)
```